# assigns in RSpec helper test is returning nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I looked everywhere but can't find what's wrong with this code. I have a helper that assigns an instance variable, and I'm trying to test this assignment in a helper spec, but the method `assigns[:variable_name]` always returns nil. I'm using RSpec 3.

Here's the helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def barra_aplicacoes
    @barra = {
      limite_links: MyGem.configuracao.limite_links_visiveis,
      incluir_deslogar: MyGem.configuracao.incluir_deslogar,
      aplicacoes: get_aplicacoes
    }

    render partial: 'layouts/my_gem/barra_aplicacoes'
  end
end
```

And here's the helper spec I'm trying to run:

```
RSpec.describe ApplicationHelper, type: :helper do
  describe '#barra_aplicacoes' do
    it 'deve setar o hash de dados da barra' do
      allow(helper).to receive(:get_aplicacoes).and_return([])
      helper.barra_aplicacoes
      #binding.pry
      expect(helper.assigns[:barra]).to be_a(Hash)
      #expect(assigns[:barra]).to be_a(Hash) (both don't work)
    end
  end
end
```

The test fails because `assigns[:barra]` is always nil. I tried to debug with pry and the assigns hash (and the helper.assigns hash) really don't have my `@barra` variable. I also have other tests on this method (like checking if it's rendering that partial), and they all work. Why isn't RSpec picking the variable up?

Comment: The method is `assigns(:barra)`, not with square brackets. Did you try? Also notice that assigns is deprecated, you should test against controller response, not what variables are assigned

Comment: `assigns(:barra)` is still giving me nil, and `helper.assigns(:barra)` doesn't take any arguments (gives me a wrong number of arguments error).

Comment: And this is a helper test, not a controller test, I'm not sure how else should I test this other than that.

Comment: Sorry missed the fact that it was a helper